# Hybris ProductListPage does not find category

Tags: templates, product, sap-commerce-cloud

here is my question. I have one ProductListPage where I want to display a single product. I have a simple Product catalog with one category "TestCategory" and one product assigned to it "TestProduct". What I want is just to display the product in my Product List Page.

However, when I access the Product List Page, there is a message stating:

Category with code 'TestCategory' not found! (Active session catalogversions: ProductTestCatalog.staged, ContentTestCatalog.staged)

Both content and product catalogs are synched and everythings seems fine. I started an indexer operation wizard and it was successful, but nothing has changed, I keep getting this message, even though the category is existing - it even comes with the name "TestCategory not found" What should I do to find it?Can you provide any ideas or solution to this problem? Maybe the problem is in my Solr Configuraiton? If yes, any ideas how to fix it will be highly appreciated. Thanks! :))

Comment: Can you please post your impex also?

Answer (score 0):

The ProductDetails Page in the hybris Accelerator does not use SOLR so it is unlikely to be that.

The error suggests that the category TestCategory is not visible to the current user in the current session.

The Active Session catalogVersions should show Online catalogs only unless you are in Preview/LiveEdit. So this suggests something is wrong.

You should try to understand the SearchRestrictions in the Session.